# What does light purple mean in Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

What's the difference between light purple and purple?
Thanks.
[image]

background:

I was trying to extract all **proto** functions from Array Type.

```
const arrayProto = Array.prototype 
const arrayMethods = Object.create(arrayProto)
```

`arrayMethods` returns `Array {}`

I found all methods are in **proto** (light purple) while none of them is counted.If I change `arrayProto` to a normal array like [1,2,3], I can get numbers by arrayMethods[i] since all the numbers are listed in **proto**.
My first thought is that light purple ones are ignored or somehow don't belong to  `arrayMethods`. However I cannot found any documents about this part of console.
Why and How to solve it?

Comment: light purple is a [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, properties may be **enumerable** or not. Non-enumerable properties are ignored by a for-in loop or `Object.keys()`. All built-in methods are non-enumerable. (This is why for-in does not list all of the methods on `Object.prototype` for every object.)

It appears that Chrome uses the dark purple to indicate an enumerable property and light purple to indicate non-enumerable. They do not need to be inherited. Demo (screenshot from Chrome 73.0.3683.103):

```js
Object.defineProperties({}, {
  foo: {enumerable: true, value: 1},
  bar: {enumerable: false, value: 2},
});
```

[image]

If you want to get the properties of an object including even unenumerable ones, you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)`. However, you will need to follow the prototype chain yourself if you want to find inherited properties.

Answer (score 0):

**Purple**

its represent index of array or a key name of the Object

**Light Purple**

its represent the [**Object.prototype**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) or [**Array.prototype**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)
.You could perform the prototype function using that object or array